# Translation of "was not publicized well"

Tags: traduction

"The event was not publicized well, so not many people attended." How should this sentence be translated? The translation for "publicize" is "faire connaître", so would it be

> L'événement n'était pas bien fait connaître, alors pas beaucoup de gens y ont assisté.

Comment: publicize is not necessarily faire connaitre. On n'a pas bien fait la promotion de l'évènement, alors peu de gens y ont assisté. faire la promotion de x: publicize

Comment: Je dirais **publicisé**, par un calque évident. Je suis assez confiant que les destinataires comprendraient. ("l'évènement n'a pas été bien publicisé")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L'événement n'a pas été bien rendu public.

L'événement n'a pas été bien annoncé.

L'événement n'a pas été bien promu (plus rare).

Comment: The form *n'a pas été bien rendu public* is clumsy and doesn't look idiomatic. The only google hit so far is precisely your reply.

Answer (score 4):

> L'événement <s>n'était pas bien fait connaître</s>

is incorrect, a grammatically correct form would be:

> L'événement **ne s'était pas** bien fait connaître

but the issue is the *événement* is not responsible of this poor publicizing.

> alors <s>pas beaucoup de gens</s> y ont assisté.

is lazy/colloquial or childish French, that should rather be:

> alors, **peu de gens** y ont assisté.

Here is one way to correct your sentence:

> *L'événement n'ayant pas bénéficié d'une promotion suffisante (ou efficace), l'assistance n'y fut pas très nombreuse*

I would rephrase it that way:

> *Faute d'une campagne d'information efficace, peu de gens assistèrent à cet événement.*

or simply

> *Faute de promotion efficace, peu de gens assistèrent à cet événement.*

Comment: publicize is not une campagne d'information.

Comment: @Lambie Not necessarily but I believe a *campagne d'information* is a common way to promote/publicize some events.

Comment: You can use the phrase to translate a verb like that. Promouvoir/promotion is the clue.

Comment: @Lambie I agree, and I already suggested *promotion* in my reply.